# Is a minor liable to pay old dues to his father on attaining majority?

Tags: minor, loan, loan-guarantee, tax-law

I had some stepfathers and an equal number of fostermothers in my life. My Stepfathers used to work in customs and central excise department of the government of INDIA. They used to be transferred from one office to another. They used to incur expenditures on account of my food, study, dresses and sometimes restaurant bills.

When I attained the majority, one of my stepfathers demanded money for the period when I was a minor and the date of my attaining majority for distribution among stepfathers or mothers who are alive. After attaining the majority this is usual I will have to pay the rest amount, He threatened to file a court case against me, I think he complained against me in the court besides informing my office/head office and his office.

I was struggling as some of the stepfathers and foster mothers have subseqently died. How I can hand over money to dead persons?

I lived in the same house with them until they died. I have not handed over a single Indian rupee to them, because I was poor and they died in succession.

Now I have enough money but I can't repay the loan because they are dead. When they needed/wanted I could not pay them any amount of money. Now I am remorseful but I can't send money to people who have already died. I have paid good amounts to religious places and I wish to pay more for their peace. 
My original mother and father died when I was a newborn.

My question is what is my legal position?  Do I have to pay the rest amount which is the total amount of the loan to any office of the government of India?

Answer (score 2):

### What loan?

People provided you, as a child, food, shelter and the necessities of life. If these people were your legal guardians then this is their **obligation**; if they weren’t then this is a **gift**.

Legally you owe nobody anything for this. Ethically and culturally, well, that’s up to you.

Comment: @Dale.M-iN ONE OR TWO CASES I WAS A LEGALLY ADOPTED CHILD, WHATEVER BE THE CASE, THIS IS MORAL OBLIGATION OF A SON ALSO IS TO PAY HIS FATHER[BROTHER, SISTER WILL SHARE]. EXCEPT IN EXTREMELY ABNORMAL CASES, NO FATHER GOES TO COURT AGAINST HIS SON. BUT I HAD TO SUFFER MENTAL TORTURE.I READ A BOOK ON COMMERCIAL LAW. AS PER THE BOOK MY FATHER WAS RIGHT. USER-26375

Comment: You have no moral obligation whatsoever towards that “man”. Please quote what that book said because you most likely misunderstood. You have to repay loans (usually), but there is no loan.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what Dale is saying, if someone gave you a loan, there would have to be a loan contract. I suppose there isn’t one, right? No contract, no loan, no repayment.

If there was a loan contract, any contract that you entered as a minor is voidable. So if your stepfather gave you say a $10,000 loan, with a signed contract, you could void that loan contract at any time and he would have no right to the money back.

If your stepfather told you “I’ll give you food and shelter, but it’s a loan that you have to repay”, that would be a contract that you entered under duress and therefore void.

Summary: As Dale said, he has no right to any money. Second, for two or three different reasons, he would still have no right to any money.

Comment: @gnsher 729-"NO CONSIDERATION NO CONTRACT".A MINOR CAN'T SIGN A CONTRACT PAPER.SO THE MINOR DOES NOT OWE ANY MONEY TO HIS STEPFATHER. HERE "EAT DRINK AND BE MERRY" APPLIES. DO I HAVE NO MORAL OBLIGATION. ONE WHO HAS SELF ESTEEM SHOULD PAY THE TOTAL AMOUNT DUE. OR THE WORLD WILL SEE I GREW UP AS AN ORPHAN IN A ORPHANAGE. MY FATHER DEPRIVED ME OF MANY FACILITIES[FORMAL AND INFORMAL] I WAS AVAILING, THEN I FOUND MYSELF NOWHERE. I COULD NOT TOLERATE HIS SCATHING REMARKS WHICH THE SPREAD IN THE OFFICES AND THE SOCIETY.  THE BITTER RELATIONSHIP WHICH GREW UP, TORMENTS ME.USER-26375

Comment: @ABHIJITBAGCHI You are asking on a law site. Re: "moral obligation," self-esteem, and scathing remark, that gets into things beyond the law. Perhaps it is philosophy, if you ask on the Philosophy SE, it will likely be closed unless you ask a question like "What philosophers have written about a child's obligation to repay the adults who feed, house, and clothe him?" If you believe it is a religious obligation, you could ask about that on the SE for your religion- for example, there are SE for Hinduism and Islam. If it is about your reputation in your community, I am not sure how we can help.

Comment: @Damila-THE relationship between a stepfather and stepson is not one of love and affection. This is not a legal problem. There are many peculiar problems in numerous families.SUCH PROBLEMS INVOLVE MANY PEOPLE. A biblical solution perhaps is "woe unto the man by whom the Son of man is betrayed, it were better for him if he were not born". MANY THANKS FOR YOUR VALUABLE COMMENT. USER-26375

Comment: @ABHIJITBAGCHI **"This is not a legal problem. "**  Exactly. Yet you asked on a law site.

Comment: @ABHIJITBAGCHI: You will pay the whole amount due. When you become a father. When you raise your own child without keeping track of the cost to hand them a bill.